# How to get a Java method's all referring classes by jars like ASM or Javassist?

Tags: java, maven, bytecode, java-bytecode-asm, javassist

As the code shows below:

```java
public class Main implements MainInter{
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        List<String> s = new ArrayList<>();
        DClassFather var = new DClassFather();
        DClassFather d = new DClass();
    }
}
```

How can I get that the method "Main: main" refers classes "java.lang.String", "java.util.ArrayList", "java.util.List", "DClassFather", "DClass"

Comment: What do you need it for?

Comment: I need it for some java bytecode analysis work later

Comment: What have you tried so far?

Comment: I tried to use Javassist, but it seems that javassist can only get a Java class' referring classes by the function ```public synchronized Collection<String> getRefClasses() ```. It cannot get a Java method's referring classes.

Comment: When you do the “some java bytecode analysis work”, this information comes for free. There is no point in collecting this information beforehand.

Answer (score 3):

There is no built in way to do this, however you could visit (or iterate over in case of asm-tree) every instruction and collect the references in a Set.

The basic concept would go like this (using asm-tree):

```
Set<String> dependencies = new HashSet<String>();

for (AbstractInsnNode insnNode : methodNode.instructions) {
    if (insnNode instanceof MethodInsnNode methodInsn) {
        dependencies.add(methodInsn.owner);
        //If you want the full references you should also get the types of the methodDescriptor
    }
}
```